# Merge array into an array of an objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, replace, lodash

I have an array and an object that has an array as one of its keys. I want to use Lodash to merge the array into the object replace its array. Here is the code...

```
array1 = [false, true, true];

object1 = {
 id: 1,
 label: 'lorem',
 description: "ipsum",
 users: [
   {
     id: 1,
     user: 'morbi',
     checked: true
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     user: 'mauris',
     checked: true
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     user: 'duis',
     checked: true
   }
 ]
}
```

What I want to do is have the booleans in array1 replace the "checked" booleans in the users array in object1. I want to use Lodash to do this since it seems like it would be much easier, but if there's another way, I'm open to that.

Any suggestions?

Comment: "*I want to use Lodash to do this since it seems like it would be much easier*" why can you not use a simple loop?

Comment: A simple loop will suffice

Answer (score 3):

Given that the arrays are of the same length, you can do this using `Array#forEach` (or `_.forEach`):

```js
const 
  array1 = [false, true, true],
  object1 = {
    id: 1,
    label: 'lorem',
    description: "ipsum",
    users: [
      { id: 1, user: 'morbi', checked: true },
      { id: 2, user: 'mauris', checked: true },
      { id: 3, user: 'duis', checked: true }
   ]
};

object1.users.forEach((user, i) => user.checked = array1[i]);

console.log(object1.users);
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but can you rewrite it so that array1 is changed with the values in object1? In other words, reverse what you did. I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that.

Comment: You can do this: ``array1.forEach((_, i, arr) => arr[i] = object1.users[i].checked);``

Comment: The answer solves the problem, but it doesn't fix the larger issue I'm having with Reactive Forms in Angular 11.

Comment: @CodeJunkie this is out of the question's scope. You can post another question targeted towards angular use case..

Comment: Thanks for your help Majed!

Answer (score 0):

Majed's answer is correct.
I'm adding this code here just in case you need to deal with immutability and requires to create new object to trigger changes.

```js
const 
  array1 = [false, true, true],
  object1 = {
    id: 1,
    label: 'lorem',
    description: "ipsum",
    users: [
      { id: 1, user: 'morbi', checked: true },
      { id: 2, user: 'mauris', checked: true },
      { id: 3, user: 'duis', checked: true }
   ]
};

function updateAnswer(obj, answers) {
  return {
    ...obj,
    users: obj.users.map((user, index) => {
      return { ...user, checked: answers[index] }
    })
  }
}

console.log(updateAnswer(object1, array1));
```